# Can any two points in the plane be assigned continuously a path between them that is transversal to two circles?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

More formally, I'm interested in continous functions
$$\Gamma : \mathbb{R}^2\times \mathbb{R}^2 \to ([0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^2)$$
such that $\Gamma(p,q)(0)=p$ and $\Gamma(p,q)(1)=q$, with the additional condition that for every $(p,q)\in \mathbb{R}^2\times \mathbb{R}^2$, we have that $\Gamma(p,q) \pitchfork X$, where $X$ is two circles of radius 1 centered in $(-2,0)$ and $(2,0)$. For the transversality condition to make sense, we require that $\Gamma(p,q)$ is smooth.

It can be seen that when $X$ is just one circle, this can be done, by composing the path that takes $p$ to the origin, and then goes back to $q$. Sadly, the same trick can't be applied to the two circles, at least as far as I can see. I suspect there is no function that satisfies these requirements, but I have not been able to show this.

I'm interested in this as it's a special case of [topological complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_complexity), and may give a strictly greater upper bound.

Edit: I'm assuming the compact open topology on $[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: What topology are you putting on the space of maps $[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}^2$? I suspect than answer will be positive for most common choices.

Comment: @Kajelad my bad, it's the compact-open topology

Comment: Whether you fix $p$ and $q$ or whether you consider a smooth map on the product less the diagonal, this follows pretty much immediately from the standard transversality theorems. See Guillemin & Pollack.

Comment: @TedShifrin Could you elaborate on the proof? I have checked the book but I'm not sure how the theorems could be used for this problem. By the standard theorems, for any $p,q$, the straight path from $p$ and $q$ is homotopic to one that is transversal to $X$. However the choice for each pair $(p,q)$ is not necessarily continuous in the above sense (at least not from the standard proof).

Comment: Look at the Transversality Extension and Homotopy Theorems. You get a homotopic map less than $\epsilon$ away. (And you can keep it unchanged in a neighborhood of $p$ and $q$, too.)

Comment: @TedShifrin I'm not sure that these suffice. If you think of the problem as finding a continuous section of a fiber bundle $\pi:E\to B$ contained in the transverse subset $T\subseteq E$, then these theorems tell you that the intersection of $T$ with each fiber is open and dense, but this is not enough to ensure the existence of a section on its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that no such map exists due to topological obstructions. Here's a rough sketch on one possible argument:

Let $C_-,C_+\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ be the left and right circles, and let $U=\mathbb{R}^2\setminus(C_+\cup C_-)$ be their compliment. Let $T\subset C^\infty([0,1],\mathbb{R}^2)$ denote the space of smooth paths in $\mathbb{R}^2$ transverse to $C_+\cup C_-$, with the compact open topology, and let $\widetilde{T}\subset T$ denote those whose endpoints do not lie in $C_+\cup C_-$. It suffices to show there is no continuous map $\Gamma:U\times U\to\widetilde{T}$ satisfying $\Gamma(p,q)(0)=p$, $\Gamma(p,q)(1)=q$. We can assume for the sake of contradiction that such a $\Gamma$ exists, and define some useful auxiliary functions:

Let $l:\widetilde{T}\to[0,1]$ be the "last intersection" function:
$$
l(\gamma)=\max\{t\in[0,1]:\gamma(t)\in C_+\cup C_-\}
$$
let $D_p:T\to\mathbb{R}$ be the miniumum Euclidean distance to $p\in\mathbb{R}^2$:
$$
D_p(\gamma)=\min\{d(p,\gamma(t)):t\in[0,1]\}
$$
and let $\theta_p:T_p\to\mathbb{R}$ be the winding number about $p\in\mathbb{R}^2$, where $T_p\subset T$ is the set of paths that do not pass through $p$:
$$
\theta_p(\gamma)=\int_0^1\frac{(\gamma_1(t)-p_1)\dot\gamma_2(t)-(\gamma_2(t)-p_2)\dot\gamma_1(t)}{\|\gamma(t)-p\|^2}
$$
Let $p_0=(-2,0)$ and $q_0=(0,0)$. Assume w.l.o.g. that the last intersection of $\Gamma(p_0,q_0)$ is with $C_-$.

Let $\alpha:[0,1]\to U\times U$ be a loop based at $(p_0,q_0)$ holding $p$ fixed and wrapping $q$ around $C_+$:
$$
\alpha(t)=\left(\binom{-2}{0},\binom{2-2\cos(2\pi t)}{-2\sin(2\pi t)}\right)
$$
Let $\varphi:[0,1]\to T$ be the rescaling of $\Gamma\circ\alpha$ to include only the segment between the last intersection and the endpoint. Note $\varphi(s)$ intersects the circles only at $\varphi(s)(0)\in C_-$
$$
\varphi(s)(t)=\Gamma(\alpha(s))((1-t)l(\Gamma(\alpha(s)))+t)
$$
Now, one needs to show the following:

- $D_p$, and $\theta_p$, $\varphi$, and $l\circ\Gamma$ are continuous on their domains.
- If $\varphi:[0,1]\to T$ is a continuous family of "good" curves and one $\varphi(s_0)$ lies strictly outside of $C_+$, then all $\varphi(t)$ lie strictly outside $C_+$ (equivalently for $C_-$) (this follows from continuity of $D_p$).
- $\theta_{(0,2)}\circ\varphi$ is well-defined and continuous.
- $\theta_{(0,2)}(\varphi(0))\neq\theta_{(0,2)}(\varphi(1))$, which is the desired contradiction.

Comment: Great, really elegant proof. Just to double check, it's actually $\theta_q(\varphi(0))\neq\theta_q(\varphi(1))$, right?

Comment: Actually, I think this argument doesn't use the transversality problem, and would show there is no continuous map $\Gamma$, but there is, take the straight path between $p$ and $q$. I think the problem is that the last intersection map $l$ is not continuous, so $\varphi$ is not continuous either.

Comment: @Shiranai To your first comment, it should be the winding number about $(0,2)$ in all cases; the typo has been corrected. To your second, it's true that it's possible to choose a path $\Gamma(p_0,q_0)$ satisfying the hypotheses, but no such path will allow $\Gamma$ to extend continuously around the loop $\alpha$. It's similar to the classical problem of showing that there is no continuous square root function $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}\to\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$. Transversality is used to ensure that the paths must avoid $C_+$, so that $\theta_{(0,2)}$ is well-defined.

Comment: thanks for your answers. I now agree that transversality would imply that the paths must avoid $C_+$, though I think formalizing that may be a bit tricky, but that seems to be another question. If you have any particular idea in mind though, I'd be happy if you share it.

Comment: @Shiranai The argument that I had in mind in the second bullet point is that if there is a $\varphi(s_1)$ which intersects $C_+$, then $D_{(0,2)}(\varphi(s_1))\le 1$. You can then apply intermediate value theorem to obtain an $s_2$ s.t. $D_{(0,2)}(\varphi(s_2))=1$, and the point on $\varphi(s_2)$ of minimum distance to $(0,2)$ is tangent to the $C_+$.